# Error While running Namenode

Tags: hadoop, namenode

While i am starting namenode i am getting the below error:

```
[sudo] password for hadoopnode1:

 * Starting Hadoop namenode:

starting namenode, logging to /var/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hdfs-namenode-
hadoopnode1.vertexcs.com.out

log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.DRFAAUDIT

log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "DRFAAUDIT".
```

Is there any key for log4j.appender.DRFAUDIT

Please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

vim /etc/alternatives/hadoop-conf/log4j.properties

add :
log4j.appender.DRFAAUDIT=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.DRFAAUDIT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

Answer (score 0):

Its a configuration issue, and too broad to be explained here.

A possible answer is:

```
# Configure local appender
log4j.appender.DRFAAUDIT=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.DRFAAUDIT.File=/var/log/audit.log
log4j.appender.DRFAAUDIT.DatePattern=.yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.DRFAAUDIT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.DRFAAUDIT.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c: %m%n
```

refer: [How to configure](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowToConfigure)